# wifi経由のアクセスをトレースする事は可能?

Tags: network

Mac本体からWifiを飛ばしてiPhoneやiPadをネットにつなげて、どのサーバーにつながっているか(IP)などを確認することは可能でしょうか?

アプリやサイトを作った時に実機でテストして、ちゃんとテストサーバーを参照しているかなどを確認したいのです。その際に不要な通信が発生していないかなどもできるだけ詳しく確認したいです。

何に関する知識が必要なのかだけでも教えていただけると助かります。

ちなみに現在はテストサーバーにアクセスした時は特定の文字列を表示して簡易的にわかるようにしたり、サーバー側でログを見たりしているのですが、複数台アクセスさせている時などめんどくさいなどデメリットがあるので今回こうした方法を試したいと思いました。

Answer (score 2):

まず「**Mac本体からWifiを飛ばしてiPhoneやiPadをネットにつなげて**」はMacをWiFiアクセスポイントとすれば可能と思われます。具体的な手順は以下のサイトに書かれています。

- [MacをWiFiアクセスポイントとして使う方法 ｜Mac](http://weekly.ascii.jp/elem/000/000/136/136392/)

次に「**どのサーバーにつながっているか(IP)などを確認する**」は、MacをWiFiアクセスポイントとした後に、iPhoneやiPadをそのWiFi経由でインターネットに繋いで、その状態でWiresharkのようなパケットキャプチャツールを使うと実現できると思います。WiresharkのMacへのインストールは以下のサイトが参考になります。

- [WiresharkをMac OS X Mavericks(10.9.4)に入れる - 戦場のプログラマー](http://blog.pg1x.com/entry/2014/07/08/231557)

Answer (score 1):

暗号化の設定にもよりますが、そういった用途ではWireSharkなどが知られています。

- http://www.forest.impress.co.jp/library/software/wireshark/

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Proxyのツールが便利です。Macですと[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)や[Burp Proxy](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)が有名です。

リクエストとレスポンスを整形して表示してくれますし、SSL通信の内容をキャプチャするのに利用できます。

Comment: 質問の用途だと、 Charles がいいかもしれない。HTTP/HTTPS 以外の通信をすることはないでしょうし、ログ整形がとても便利です。